# Div positioning for a fluid layout

Tags: css, position, html

I'm trying to figure out how to get my planned layout.

I am trying to place a white border around the page (when scrolling content in the container the border should still be there on top). Right now there is a border but content can still place over the border when resizing the browser window or if there is too much content in the content_area. Trying to get the layout pretty fluid so it will resize ok on any device just stacking content and the menu on top of eachother.

I am also trying to center the content_area in the container.

I think the nav_area staying at the fixed bottom center location always visible on top of any content is the only part working as planned right now.

Help much appreciated!

This is my html:

```
<div id="container_border">

    <!-- CONTAINER -->
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content_area">

            <div class='thumb' data-container='project1_container'>
             </div>

            <div class='thumb' data-container='project2_container'>
             </div>

            <div class='thumb' data-container='project3_container'>
             </div>

            <div class='thumb' data-container='project4_container'>
             </div>

            <div class='thumb' data-container='project5_container'>
             </div>

            <div class='thumb' data-container='project6_container'>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav_area">
            <div id="nav">
                <div class='link' data-container='a_container'><a href="#">A</a>
             </div>
             <div class='link' data-container='b_container'><a href="#">B</a>
             </div>
             <div class='link' data-container='c_container'><a href="#">C</a>
             </div>
             <div class='link' data-container='d_container'><a href="#">D</a>
             </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
    </div>
```

This is my css:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: futura;
}

#container_border {
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
background: #fff;
}

#container {
position: fixed;
display: block;
top:10px;left:10px;right:10px;bottom:10px;
vertical-align: center;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FDC0B1, #EAA6C9); /* For Safari */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FDC0B1, #EAA6C9); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FDC0B1, #EAA6C9); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#FDC0B1, #EAA6C9); /* Standard syntax (must be last)*/ 

}

#content_area {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}

.link {
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-left: 15px;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

.thumb { 
float: left;
background-color: #ccc;
display: block;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
margin: 30px;
}

#nav_area {
position: fixed;
clear: both;
display: block;
height: auto;
z-index: 2;
left:10px;right:10px;bottom:10px;

}

#nav {
position: relative;
font-style: italic;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#nav a {
color: #381cdf;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HPUb6/)

Comment: pls put it into something like jsfiddle

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HPUb6/

Comment: You have too many `position:fixed` elements. The only element that should be fixed is the navigation it sounds like. You could simply add a white border to the `body` element.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more please? Wouldn't I have the same problem not being able to scroll content that goes outside of the content area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure if is what you need but , this is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/HPUb6/4/

using `display:inline-block` and `text-align: center` will center your thumbs.

```
#content_area {
 text-align:center;
}
.thumb { 
display: inline-block;
}
```

I made another changes on the layout using `border` and removing fixed positions

Comment: This jsfiddle is spot on. One small thing is that the content area with the gradient as background doesn't go all the way down to the border. Can't really figure out how to make it go all the way out to the white border.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are after (if not, please include a diagram) add this:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and change this to:

```
.thumb {
    width: 16.6%;
}
```

Change the `16.6%;` on how you want your breakpoints, this is `100 / 6` .

http://jsfiddle.net/HPUb6/1/

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply! Setting overflow:hidden; It gives the right effect but I would still like to scroll to see content that actually "overflows" the container div's borders. Setting the width to 16.6% doesn't seem to work for me here or in the jsfiddle.